# Is it possible to have a reference pulse interpolator for a CNC machine with dc drive?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, manufacturing-engineering, cnc, product-engineering

Is it possible to have a reference pulse interpolator for a CNC machine with a dc drive? it should work with alternating current drive but I am not sure about the direct current drive. please help me getting its answer. thanks

Comment: Is a reference pulse interpolator another name for a resolver?